# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContex

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, javabeans

i have this code which is not working.

```
<jsp:useBean id="abbreviationlist" class="AbbreviationListType"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="abbreviationlist" property="id"/>
            <table>
                <c:forEach items="${abbreviationlist.list}" var="abbreviation">
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
```

and i have the class AbbreviationListType with set and get methods for the list- 
get singnature is =

```
public List<AbbreviationType> getList()
```

can someone please point out what i am doing wrong ?
cause this doesnt work and i get this stack trace:

> javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContex;
>   at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.unExposeVariables(LoopTagSupport.java:620)
>   .....................

here is my WEB-INF/lib

[image: WEB-INF/lib]

and my catalina/common/lib
[image: catalina/common/lib]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the wrong version of something. Remove all `el-api`, `jsp-api` and the `jstl*` jars from your lib folder. They are shipped with your servlet container

Comment: from the WEB-INF/lib directory ?

Comment: i did that (removed el-api.jar the other was not there )but still got the same error message.

Comment: @yossi - try getting rid of the jstl ones as well.