# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ValueExpression

Tags: exception, jsp, jstl, el

i am using tomcat 5.5.12
i have this code in a jsp file :

```
<jsp:useBean id="abbreviationlist" class="lexicon.contents.types.AbbreviationListType"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="abbreviationlist" property="id"/>
<table>
  <c:forEach items="${abbreviationlist.list}" var="abbreviation">
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

i get this error message -

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax/el/ValueExpression
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:272)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
>
> root cause
>           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/el/ValueExpression

i tried downloadin jstl 1.1 (standard.jar, jstl.jar)
and putting them inside catalina/commun/lib and inside the WEB-INF/lib directory.
that didnt help either.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my project we have `el-api.jar` that contains `javax/el/ValueExpression`. Do you have that jar in classpath?

Comment: i now have it but now i get this javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;

Comment: Its in `jsp-api.jar`. Add that as well. But these should already be in your tomcat common lib folder

Comment: problem solved - solution is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253954/jsp-use-jstl-to-for-iterating-over-a-list-from-a-jsp-bean i had to remove files , and put the el-api only in the catalina/common/lib folder