# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;

Tags: java, jsp, maven, jstl

I am getting error when i execute the my project on server

```
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:858)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:791)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.loginPage_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.loginPage_jsp:324)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
    javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.unExposeVariables(LoopTagSupport.java:587)
    javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doFinally(LoopTagSupport.java:323)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.loginPage_jsp._jspx_meth_c_forEach_0(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.loginPage_jsp:365)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.loginPage_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.loginPage_jsp:143)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 logs.
```

currently I am using jstl 1.2 in my pom.xml.
This error starting coming when i used forEach loop in jsp.

```
<c:forEach var ="entry" items="${appList }">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href=""><c:out value="${entry }" /></a></li>
</c:forEach>
```

Can someone help me to solve this question.

Comment: can someone help me. I got stuck in this and not able to find any solutioon.

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253954/java-lang-nosuchmethoderrorjavax-servlet-jsp-pagecontext-getelcontextljavax-e