# Runs successfully in Tomcat7 but giving error in tomcat9 in centOS

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat9

I have a project in java. Which was currently running in Tomcat-7, JAVA-8 and postgres-9.3. I updated it to openjdk-11 and postgres-13 and tried to deploy it in tomcat9, but it is giving this error.

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object 
  org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(java.lang.String, java.lan$
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:666)
    at org.apache.jsp.layout1_jsp._jspService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
```

I have tried solutions like playing with versions of jar in my WEB-INF/lib folder, but didn't work.

Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286790/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-jsp-pagecontext-getelcontextljavax) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698459/tomcat-9-nosuchmethoderror) solutions.

Comment: So you have java code in your JSP ?  Not a good idea.

Comment: Yes I have java code.

Answer (score 1):

You should clean the `$CATALINA_BASE/work` directory of your Tomcat installation. You clearly have `*.java` and `*.class` files there which were compiled with the Tomcat 7 version of Jasper.

Before deleting the files, stop Tomcat.

This should solve your `NoSuchMethodError`, but the exception that triggered this message is still in your JSP. As remarked by Scary Wombat, you should consider using only [EL expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Expression_Language) and [JSTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Standard_Tag_Library) tags in your JSP pages.